# Creating a dictionary from two lists but keeping the minimum values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working with a dictionary, and I'm having a problem, so let's say I have two lists that I need to create a dict, I know, I can use zip to do this, but the thing is, the list I'm using for `keys`  ( `list1` ) have similar tuples. This is just an example, the lists can have more elements, but the `len`  in both lists are always the same.

```
list1 = [(3, 2), (2, 4), (2, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 3)]

list2 = [68, 34, 29, 29, 3, 59]

mydict = dict(zip(list1, list2))

print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
{(3, 2): 68, (2, 4): 29, (4, 3): 59, (4, 2): 3}
```

I know that the keys are unique, and if two keys are the same, the associated value will be the last one to appear, but what I need it's that if two keys are the same, then, the associated value needs to be the minimum. For example, in `list1` I have two tuples repeated  `(2,4)`  with associated values of 34 and 29, so when the dictionary is created I need to keep the 29, and the other duplicated tuple is `(4,3)`  with values of 29 and 59, and if the dictionary is created I want the value to be 29, not 59.
**my desired output**:

```
{(3, 2): 68, (2, 4): 29, (4, 3): 29, (4, 2): 3}
```

There is some way I can achieve this? Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with

```
keys = [(3, 2), (2, 4), (2, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
values = [68, 34, 29, 29, 3, 59]
```

Make key-value pairs that are sorted by value, descending, then build the dict from that:

```
>>> dict(sorted(zip(keys, values), key=lambda x: -x[1]))
{(3, 2): 68, (4, 3): 29, (2, 4): 29, (4, 2): 3}
```

It's the same idea as your existing `dict(zip())` combination but re-ordering the values before building the dictionary, such that entries with lower values appear later - therefore, the minimum value for the key is last to appear.

Comment: Of course, you don't need to do it all in one line.

Comment: I mean this is great! Gotta love that one liners, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

one way is to sort the entries so that minimum value is last in the list:

```
def get_value(pair): return pair[1]

list1 = [(3, 2), (2, 4), (2, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 3)]

list2 = [68, 34, 29, 29, 3, 59]

mydict = dict(sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=get_value, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to do a complicated, convoluted one liner or comprehension, a simple for loop will perform fine and maintain readability. My suggestion would be something like this

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2):
    mydict = {}
    for k, v in zip(list1,list2):
        if (k not in mydict) or (mydict[k] > v):
            mydict[k] = v
    return mydict

list1 = [(3, 2), (2, 4), (2, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 3)]

list2 = [68, 34, 29, 29, 3, 59]

mydict = merge_lists(list1, list2)

print(mydict)

# mydict = {(3, 2): 68, (2, 4): 29, (4, 3): 29, (4, 2): 3}
```

If you want to play with it more, some further ideas would be to sort list 2 and move the indices of list1 in tandem. Then, with that structure, if you get a repeated element in list1 you know it must it must have come second. You wouldn't really get any perfomance boost or other benefit, but it is an alternative.

Comment: I approve of not trying to force it into a one liner, but why are you using `for i in range(len())` instead of just `for k,v in zip(list1,list2)`? it would greatly clean up the contents of that loop. As well you could use the condition `if (k not in mydict) or (mydict[k] > v):` so you don't have the nested `if`s.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You're right, that is way cleaner (been doing too much C lately ;)), thanks for the suggestion. Made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to fill `mydict` step-by-step:

```py
list1 = [(3, 2), (2, 4), (2, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 3)]

list2 = [68, 34, 29, 29, 3, 59]

mydict = {}
for k,v in zip(list1,list2):
    if k in mydict:
        mydict[k] = min(mydict[k],v)
    else:
        mydict[k] = v

print(mydict)
```

There must be IMO a one-liner solution if desired :-)

Answer (score 1):

```py
from operator import itergetter
from itertools import groupby

pairs = sorted(zip(list1, list2))
minima = {
    key: min(value for _, value in group)
    for key, group in groupby(sorted(pairs), itemgetter(0))
}
```